# Why is this small signal model incorrect?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-design, bjt, small-signal

Here is the model I was told to redraw by replacing the transistors with their mid frequency small signal model:

[image: original model]

And here is my attempt at doing so:

[image: attempt]

Upon receiving feedback, I was informed that the Rb resistors are missing. I think I made the mistake of not short circuiting the capacitors but where would the Rb resistors go and why?

Comment: DC bias is needed for conduction

Comment: Although I can guess what you perhaps mean with "Rb resistors" - it is quite unsufficient to mention such a symbol without any explanation. In such a case, you cannot expect a substantial answer.